# Show selected row in gridview

Tags: c#, radgridview

I have a data entry form with a `RadGridView`. The data is indexed alphabetically in the main field of the row. When I add a new row and press `update`, off course it goes to its place in the row order. But I don't only want that the new row will be selected, but i also want that my grid window will be shown. When I was using the default `GridView` in C# this code worked perfectly:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int id = 0;            
    id = Convert.ToInt32(lblId.Text);               
    foreach (var dgr in gridViewCompanies.Rows)
    {
        if (dgr.Cells[0].Value.Equals(tbl.ID))
        {
            dgr.IsSelected = true;
            dgr.Cells[0].IsSelected = true;
            gridViewCompanies.FirstRowIndex = dgr.Index;
            break;
        }
    }
 }
```

(I just copied this related part of the code)

But now that I am using `RadGridView` (for some other reason) that last line `gridViewCompanies.FirstRowIndex = dgr.Index;` seems not to be working. That means my new row *is* selected but the view won't show it. I have to scroll down to find the newly added row.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what finally worked:

```
private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = 0;            
        id = Convert.ToInt32(lblId.Text);               
        foreach (var dgr in gridViewCompanies.Rows)
        {
            if (dgr.Cells[0].Value.Equals(tbl.ID))
            {
                dgr.IsSelected = true;
                dgr.Cells[0].IsSelected = true;GridTableElement tableElement = this.gridViewCompanies.CurrentView as GridTableElement;
                        tableElement.ScrollToRow(dgr.Index);

                break;
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    private void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = 0;            
        id = Convert.ToInt32(lblId.Text);               
        foreach (var dgr in gridViewCompanies.Rows)
        {
            if (dgr.Cells[0].Value.Equals(tbl.ID))
            {
                dgr.IsSelected = true;
                dgr.Cells[0].IsSelected = true;

                this.radGridView.TableElement.VScrollBar.Value = dgr.Index;
                break;
            }
        }
     }
```

Try this code

Comment: So You select row but not highline it?

Comment: No, it is highlighted and everything. The thing is, for example if I have added a new row that starts with "F", after update it indexed in All other rows start with F (which may be lower in my view). But I want the grid to scroll to where that selected row is and show it to me. This Code worked perfectly with the default grid. It doesn't work with telerik radgrid

Comment: Are you try 'ScrollIntoView'?

Comment: Ye, you use Telerik Controls for winforms?

Comment: yes. How do you suggest I use it here? plz show me in the code above.

Comment: 'this.radGridView.TableElement.VScrollBar.Value = dgr.Index;' this must work.

Comment: still not working. I tried it in different ways. I am starting to think I am sabotaging it in some other part of the code.

Comment: Thank s so much  @mwisnicki for your help